# Reading More Than One Slave Sequentially With Pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus, master-slave, raspberry-pi4, pymodbus

***2 slaves(devices) are working. I use slave units #2 and #5. MPR_46S in #5, Thermometer in #2. Slave addresses are not read sequentially, so I need to read an empty slave address that i named 'Slave jump'***

```
NSlave=[2,5]
Clientnames=["client0","client1","client2","client3",] 

def Find_Device(NSlave,Clientnames):
    i=0
    print("searching devices")
    Devices=[]
    S_Slave=[]
    for i in range(len(NSlave)):

        Clientnames[i].connect()
        # check MPR_46S
        result = Clientnames[i].read_holding_registers(address=0xEC00,count=1,unit=NSlave[i])
        if not result.isError():
            if result.registers==[41223]:
                Devices.append("MPR_46S")
                S_Slave.append(NSlave[i])
                print("device found , Energy-Meter( MPR_46S) ")
            else:
                print("unsuccessful, meter")
        else:
            print('Errory >>>>  {}' , format(result)  )
        Clientnames[i].close()
     
        ####################################### slave_jump
        Clientnames[i].connect()
        result = Clientnames[i].read_holding_registers(address=0x0003,count=1,unit=200)
        Clientnames[i].close()
        ####################################### slave_jump
    
    
        result = Clientnames[i].read_holding_registers(address=0x0003,count=1,unit=NSlave[i])
        Clientnames[i].connect()
        print(Clientnames[i].connect())
        # check Term
        if not result.isError():
            if result.registers == [1]:
                Devices.append("Term")
                S_Slave.append(NSlave[i])
                print("device found ,term")
            
            else:
                print("unsuccessful,term")
        else:
            print('Errory >>>>  {}' , format(result))
        Clientnames[i].close() 
 
        ####################################### slave_jump
        Clientnames[i].connect()
        result = Clientnames[i].read_holding_registers(address=0x0003,count=1,unit=201)
        Clientnames[i].close()
        ####################################### slave_jump

        i+=1
        result.registers=[]
    print(Devices)
    print(S_Slave)
    return (Devices,S_Slave)
```

***I wonder the reason for this. I would like to use if there is a better method***

Comment: Please simplify your code down to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (I assume this will be a call to connect and two/three calls to read_holding_registers). Please also add details of what happens without 'Slave jump'.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, can you clarify your actual question?